# Replacing characters of a string in a particular sequence

Tags: java, string

The `String` `word` contains a character `]` at more than one place. I want to replace any character before the `]` by `l`, and any character after by `r`.

For example, the `String` defined below:

```
String word="S]RG-M]P";
```

Should be converted to:

```
String word="l]rG-l]r";
```

When I tried by the following code:

```
String word="S]RG-M]P";
char[] a = word.toCharArray();

for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
    if (a[i]==']'){
        a[i+1]='r';
        a[i-1]='l';
    }
}
```

It changes the right side of `]` by `r`, but fails left to it by `l`. I need help to get the required results.

Comment: No, that works for me... print out `new String(a)` afterwards. On the other hand, you need to consider what happens if the first or last character is `]`.

Comment: `.toCharArray()` makes a _copy_ of the char array; `String` is immutable. Modifying the returned array doesn't modify the `String` this array is issued from.

Comment: @Jon Skeet:']' will never be as first or last character. I am quite new to java. Kindly  give me just more detail to print it as I am confused here. I mean a line of print code.

Comment: Well just `System.out.println(new String(a));`. That will print it out. You should consider using a regular expression instead, but the code you've got should work...

Comment: Will not work if the first character is `]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String word = "S]RG-M]P";

    char[] a = word.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 1; i < a.length-1; i++) {//@Jon Skeet again is right X2 :)

        //no need now, for loop bound changed
        //if(i+1>a.length){
    //      continue;
    //  }


        if (a[i] == ']') {

            //no need now, for loop bound changed
            //@Jon Skeet you are right, this handles the case :)
            //if(i==0 || i == a.length-1){
                //continue;
            //}

            a[i + 1] = 'r';
            a[i - 1] = 'l';
        }
    }

    String outt = new String(a);
    System.out.print(outt);
}// main
```

Comment: also added a fix to @Jon Skeet case :)
and if(i+1>a.length) to avoid getting arrayIndexOutOfBound ;)

Comment: Why would you not just change the loop bounds? `for (int i = 1; i < a.length - 1; i++)`. *Far* more readable.

Comment: you are right @Jon Skeet, and we have saved 1/1000000 millisecond of cpu :)
answer was edited

Comment: You've still missed half of it - you can change *both* bounds, and get rid of the `if` at the start of the loop. Basically, keep the original code exactly as it was *except* the `for` loop bounds.

Comment: done, :( one should not write a code at weekend night, i am out of coverage now :)

Comment: Is it possibe to tweek this code to change the string 'word' to "l]rWWl]r"  ? If it is so please help as it is my final and real requirement.

Comment: else if (a[i] != 'r' && a[i] != 'l') {a[i]='W';}

Answer (score 1):

```
 String word="S]RG-M]P";
 word.replaceAll(".]." , "l]r");
```

using regex and string methods is useful in this situation

Comment: Errr no, that would be `.replaceAll()`; `.replace()` takes string literals

Comment: This is a wonderful short method. Kindly help me to change this  'word'   to  "l]rWWl]r" . This is my final need.

Answer (score 1):

```
StringBuilder word = new StringBuilder("S]RG-M]P");
int index = word.indexOf("]");
while(index > 0){
    word.setCharAt(index-1, 'l');
    word.setCharAt(index+1, 'r');
    index = word.indexOf("]", index+1);
}
System.out.println(word);
```

Comment: :You have provided great and easy method. Could you guide me to extend this method to change rest of characters (other than l,r ,]) to W to get this string to "l]rWWl]r". If it can be done my problem is 100% over.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i=0 ; i<word.length();i++){  
    char  a =  word.charAt(i);
    String after =null;
    if( Character.toString(a).equals("]")){
        int j = i-1;
        int k = i+1;
        char b =   word.charAt(j);
        char c =   word.charAt(k);
        modifyword= word.replace( Character.valueOf(b).toString(), "l");
        after=  modifyword.replace( Character.valueOf(c).toString(), "r");
        word = after;
    }
}
```